Find the smallest distance between the graphs of the function
I want to find the smallest distance between the graphs of functions $$y = e^{2024x} \quad \text{and} \quad y = \frac{1}{2024} \ln x.$$
The distance between the graphs of functions corresponds to the distance between parallel tangents to these graphs.
How can I solve this using Mathematica?

What have you tried?  Have you even plotted these functions?

Also, please use MathJax to typeset your equations.

_MathJax _? I much rather see plain text Wolfram Language code that I can copy and paste. Best of both code and $\LaTeX$

Looks like it was supposed to be solved analytically without use of Mathematica. The answer is $\frac{1+\log (2024)}{1012 \sqrt{2}}$.

@RomaLee What has your answer, wherever from, to do with the result we are looking for?

@UlrichNeumann It is an answer to the question in the title.

@RomaLee Why didn't you show the way you found this result in an answer?

@UlrichNeumann Because it was obtained without Mathematica, but with math. As I said, I believe, this question has little to do with Mathematica. E.g., it may be some kind of assignment. In this case I don't want to explain the solution.

tangent-condition isn't  necessary I think:
NMinimize[{(y1[x1] - y2[x2])^2 + (x1 - x2)^2, x2 > 0}, {x1, x2} ]
(*{0.000036216, {x1 -> -0.00376128, x2 -> 0.000494071}}*)


$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

y1[x_] = E^(2024 x);
y2[x_] = Log[x]/2024;

If the parallel tangents must be for the same values of x
sol = Solve[y1'[x] == y2'[x], x, Reals]


sol // N

(* {{x -> 2.43986*10^-7}} *)

dist1 = EuclideanDistance[{x, y1[x]}, {x, y2[x]}] /. sol[[1]]


Approximately,
dist1 // N

(* 1.00802 *)

If the parallel tangents can be for different values of x
{dist2, arg} = Minimize[{
     EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1[x1]}, {x2, y2[x2]}],
     y1'[x1] == y2'[x2], x2 > 0}, {x1, x2}] //
   RootReduce // Simplify


Approximately,
{dist2, arg} // N

(* {0.00601798, {x1 -> -0.00376128, x2 -> 0.000494071}} *)

